# How to map data from one column based on another column in perl

Tags: perl, data-mapping

please help. I'm very new to Perl and coding, I have a big file with 15 columns and some with missing information. What I'm trying to do, is select column[13] with missing information and column[4] with no missing information; and then use column[4] as a key to map to column[2] and print all lines in column[2].

Here's how my data file looks like (tab delimited):

```
BC000   1   1   2   3   F       3   51                  51  
BC000   0   2           M                                   999
BC000   0   3   37  36  F                               65  
BC000   0   4   2   3   M                               50  50
BC000   0   5   2   3   F           45                  47  46
BC000   0   6   2   3   F       3   42                      
BC000   0   7   2   3   M                                   999
BC000   0   8   2   3   F       3                       42  
BC000   0   9   2   3   F       1                       39  
BC000   0   10  2   3   F       3                       35  
BC000   0   11  45  8   M                               11  
BC000   0   12  45  8   F                               9
```

All motherIDs, column[4] will have an individualID, column[2] (the same as motherID)

Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $filename = 'file.txt';

open (FILE, "<", $filename) or die "Cannot open file $!";

my @data = <FILE>;
my @column;
my $motherID;



foreach my $line (@data)
{
    @column = split ( /\t/, $line);

    if ($column[13] eq "" && $column[4] ne "" ) #missing YOB, but with mother ID
    {
        $motherID = join($column[2],$column[4]);


        if ("$motherID" eq "$column[2]")
        {
            print "$line\t\n";
        } 
    }
}
```

I tried this but it doesn't return any values. Can you please help? I'm really new to this, I'm trying to write a script to avoid mapping the columns manually in MS Excel as it's a big file with over 4000 rows. Many many thanks in advance!

Comment: Just in case: Do you know that `$column[2]` is the third (3rd) column? Indexing starts with 0.  So same with `$column[13]` (it's the 14th one) and `$column[4]` (the 5th one.)

Comment: I suggest to remove those (repeated!) "please help," all of them.  You've asked a question, that says it all.

Comment: The `$motherID` cannot be equal to `$column[2]` in the `if` condition, since it is made by `join`ing that very `$column[2]` with the non-empty `$column[4]` on the previous line.  So this code will never print.  And I don't see what the logic should be...?

Comment: It is not clear from the data you have provided which values correspond to which columns. E.g., do the values '999' belong to column 13,14 or 15 (indices 12,13,14)?
Can you use commas instead of tabs? (When you copied and pasted the tabs are converted to spaces I think.)